# Analog of scipy's labeled_comprehension "along axis"

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, vectorization

If you have a one-dimensional `numpy` array `points` of length `n` and a one-dimnensional array with `k` unique labels with the same shape, [scipy.ndimage.measurements.labeled_comprehension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.labeled_comprehension.html) allows you to apply general function `f` to elements corresponding to each label without making `k` passes over the entire array. This is helpful when the number of labels is large relative to `n` and `f` accepts a *flat* array.

However, what if you would like to apply a function `f` that operates on a *non-flat* array? In my case, I was trying to calculate the diameter of each cluster in a set of two-dimensioal points annotated by cluster. Here is the setup:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.ndimage import labeled_comprehension


# set up fake data
np.random.seed(0)
n_centroids = 3
centroids = np.random.rand(n_centroids, 2)
cluster_sizes = np.random.randint(3, 5, size=n_centroids)
# labels for each point for clusters ranging from 1 to n_centroids inclusive
labels = np.repeat(np.arange(n_centroids), cluster_sizes) + 1
# random points around each centroid
points = np.zeros((cluster_sizes.sum(), 2))
points[:,0] = np.repeat(centroids[:,0], cluster_sizes)
points[:,1] = np.repeat(centroids[:,1], cluster_sizes)
points += 0.05 * np.random.randn(cluster_sizes.sum(), 2)

# black box function; we can assume that
# pts.shape[0] is variable
# pts.shape[1:] is fixed
def diameter(pts):
  # print(pts)
  # need at least 3 points to construct the convex hull
  if pts.shape[0] <= 1:
    return 0
  if pts.shape[0] == 2:
    return ((pts[0] - pts[1])**2).sum()
  # two points which are fruthest apart will occur as vertices of the convex hull
  hull = spatial.ConvexHull(pts)
  candidates = pts[spatial.ConvexHull(pts).vertices]
  return spatial.distance_matrix(candidates, candidates).max()
```

My attempt to apply `labelled_comprehension` was as follows:

```
labeled_comprehension(points, np.stack((labels, labels), 1), None, diameter, np.float, None)
```

Resulting in the following traceback:

```
 ***debug printout of argument to diameter***
 [0.54606175 0.70982384 0.61708686 0.71030458 0.42751578 0.69253658
 0.57922483 0.59353398 0.53885592 0.61675172 0.59887815 0.59936469
 0.60759051 0.61581654 0.48206846 0.69325341 0.47792915 0.76500534
 0.40335361 0.65921638]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-79-4c2d0fdb5c38> in <module>()
----> 1 labeled_comprehension(points, np.stack((labels, labels), 1), None, diameter, np.float, None)

1 frames

<ipython-input-77-99537dd58821> in diameter(pts)
     25     return ((pts[0] - pts[1])**2).sum()
     26   # two points which are fruthest apart will occur as vertices of the convex hull
---> 27   hull = spatial.ConvexHull(pts)
     28   candidates = pts[spatial.ConvexHull(pts).vertices]
     29   return spatial.distance_matrix(candidates, candidates).max()

qhull.pyx in scipy.spatial.qhull.ConvexHull.__init__()

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

As we see, `diameter` received a flat array as input.

I can achieve the desired output by iteratively masking over each label, e.g.

```
def desired_output(points, labels, f=diameter):
  return np.array([f(points[labels==i]) for i in np.unique(labels)])

# [0.1904019410968485, 0.06874095082563453, 0.12943266211372922]
```

However, this requires `k` (number of clusters) passes over `n` elements (points).

Instead, I would like to do something like this:

```
def desired_output2(points, labels, f=diameter):
  return labelled_comprehension_along_axis(points, labels, f=diameter, axis=-1)
```

**Question**: how can one implement a vectorized version of `labelled_comprehension` that accepts a black box function `f` that operates on an array of shape `(k, const)` and returns a scalar, without making `O(k)` passes over the input array?

Ideally, this can be extended to a case where `const` is an "ntuple" of dimensions, similarly to `_over_axes` functions.